# [[Bash]] Search for combined Expressions in every row

Tags: bash

I am very new to Bash Scripting and I have a question regarding my CheckOurCodingRules.sh script:

I want to search for every 'hPar,' in a textfile and if found it should be checked if there is a also a 'const' in the same row.

Thats what I got so far but there is something wrong here:

```
while read line
    do
        if [[ $line == *hPar\,* ]] && [[ $line == *const\*]];then
            DOCUMENTATION_TEST_A=1

        else
            echo DOCUMENTATION_TEST_A=0
        fi
    done < $INPUT_FILE

    if [[DOCUMENTATION_TEST_A=0]];then
    echo "error: Rule1: No const before hpar"
    fi
```

Comment: Hello Andi and welcome to [so]! Please do not add info in comments. Instead, [edit] the post and add it there. Also, could you provide a [mcve] so we can play around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your script, see the code below which works for me:

```
DOCUMENTATION_TEST_A=0          # initial value

while read line                                                                 
    do                   
        # spaces between conditional and brackets, no backslashes                                                       
        if [[ $line == *hPar,* ]] && [[ $line == *const* ]]                            
        then                                                                    
            DOCUMENTATION_TEST_A=1                                              
            break  # optional, no need to scan the rest of the file
        fi
done < $INPUT_FILE                                                                      

# spaces and $, -eq is used for numerical comparisons
if [[ $DOCUMENTATION_TEST_A -eq 0 ]];   
then                                       
    echo "error: Rule1: No const before hpar"                                   
fi
```

A cleaner solution would be to use `grep`:

```
if ! grep "hPar," $INPUT_FILE | grep "const" >/dev/null 
then
    echo "error: Rule1: No const before hpar"                                   
fi
```

Comment: You are the best mpurg, I am just starting to get into all of that